# How to call an AngularJS controller function from Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

How Can I call a function in an AngularJS controller from an angular 8 component.

Angular Component - myangular.component.ts

```
export class MyAngularComponent {
  ...
doWork(){
    //call DoSomeWork function of myController
}
...
}
```

Angular Js controller - myAngularJsController.js

```
myApp.Controller('myController',
...
$scope.DoSomeWork(data){
   //do some work here
}
...
)
```

Comment: please remove the `angular` tag as it's related to `angularjs`

Comment: You'll need to use NgUpgrade if you want to run a hybrid AngularJs/Angular2 app, they don't mesh out of the box.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon I used the angular tag since I need to know how can I call the function from Angular

Comment: no nevermind, i'm sorry

Comment: @NoorMuhammed, were you able to figure out the solution for this, as I am facing the same issue at the moment

Comment: if it is helpful for anyone in future, I ended up raising an even in angular 2 component ad handling the event in angularJS directive